# Looping through a list of table name and handle with the column of each table

Tags: r

I have 8 table data, i put it into c() vector

```
speech <- c(fed_df_d_1985,fed_df_d_1995,fed_df_d_2005,fed_df_d_2015,fed_df_r_1985,fed_df_r_1995,fed_df_r_2005,fed_df_r_2015)
```

and use loop function to loop through each table, and create the wordcloud for each as follow:

```
for (i in speech) {
  i$variable  <- gsub("_", " ", i$variable)
  wordcloud(word = i$variable[1:20],
            freq = i$D[1:20])
}
```

but it has error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Try putting it into a `list()` instead of a vector `c()`. Access the elements by using `speech[[i]]` and, for example, the columns of the data.frames in the list via `speech[[fed_df_d_1995]]["variable"]`. Instead of using a `for` loop you could consider `lapply`.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think lists are recursive objects so they can be accessed via $,  vectors are atomic so they can't.

Comment: @MartinGal thank you so much, that's helpful. this is one of my usual mistake when running code, I don't know when should I use list() or vector() when I apply function, or assign value, or handling data in a table like this. Can you instruct How should I improve this problem?